# Timeout expired error -- NOT a sql server timeout

Tags: asp.net, exception, timeout

I've set up a scheme where any exceptions on my client's web site (an ASP.NET 2.0 application) are emailed to me. Almost every night (usually it happens at night) I get errors like the following:

```
Error: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Stack Trace:
   at carart.products.Page_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.OnError(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.products_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

The last location is Page_Error because I have a Page_Error handler that redirects to an Error.aspx page and displays a message to the user. It is before it does the redirect that it sends out the email detailing the error.

I'm really can't tell at what point in my code this is failing, but I'm assuming that it doesn't even get to Page_Load since it doesn't show up in the stack trace.

I get at least 3 or 4 of these every night -- but sometimes in the daytime as well, and sometimes it interferes with customer checkouts and other things vital to my client's business.

How can I debug this? What property do I have to set to tell it to wait longer to connect to the server?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, you may want to investigate further why that timeout is happening, but in order to increase the timeout (you're probably best off setting this as page specific), you can do this in your web.config:

```
<location path="somefile.aspx">
    <system.web>
            <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180"/>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try. But ... how would I go about "investigating", when the error seems to occur before my code is executed? I have checked the IIS logs, but, naturally, nothing shows up since it can't even connect to the server. How can I find out what is slowing it down? (The site is on a shared server, BTW, so I don't have access to IIS or much of anything else.)

Comment: Hmm what about the event logs on the server? Although you mentioned it's a shared server, couldn't you request the logs?

Comment: I know you mentioned that it's not SQL, but to be *extra sure* have a look at what goes on in `carart.products` and if it's SQL heavy, then you may want to adjust the property for the timeout for that. See here if that's the case: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout.aspx

Comment: What log would a timeout show up in? How could it show up in ANY log on the server, when it could not connect to the server?

Comment: @Cynthia It would show up in the Event logs on the server under Application. It could connect to the server, that's not the issue you're having (if it couldn't connect to the server, you wouldn't even get as far as an exception)